# Disable unsafe USB removal warning on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, usb, eject

Is there any way to remove the warning message that pops up on Mac OS X when you remove a USB device without ejecting it properly first?

Comment: It will save you from a lot of "don't" comments if you indicate that you know what you're doing... (You *do* know what you're doing, right?)

Comment: What version of OSX? And do you want to disable that warning or *every* warning?

Comment: See [this thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly)

Comment: @Raystafarian Good find, but apparently [that will also disable e.g. iCal notifications when iCal isn't running](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2004/Jun/msg00106.html). So it's not without side effects.

Comment: You could just eject it. This is better, anyway. What version of OSX?

Comment: A followup question might be: what is the absolute simplest and quickest way to properly eject a USB device?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5863810/do-i-really-need-to-eject-usb-drives-before-removing-them - Related and good read, but I'm aslo not happy with the answer there. Still hoping for a safe-without-ejecting removal method.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike others may say, "*creating an arc across the pins*" can not damage your drive; the power pins are offset from the data pins exactly to prevent this from happening.

The reason you have to eject a USB disk or SD card is that OS X mounts it to a path like any *nix system and might not flush the buffers before you properly dismount the device. You could end up with partial data on the device or errors in the FS.

Windows gets around it by defaulting to flushing the buffers on removable devices, but this results in slower access to the device. For similar behavior, you need a way to tell it to write fully to the drive everything sent to it. I don't know enough about OS X internals to tell you if the FAT driver is capable of that.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a normal message board; to respond to another answer, you need to use the comment link on the other answer. The rest of your answer is good, so I removed the comment part. You should post the comment on the other answer to engage that answer's poster in conversation.

Comment: IMO, it's fine to address other answers in your answer as long as it's related to your answer and not a completely separate remark.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to address other answers. Sometimes, like this one, he could actually be self contained rather than referencing the other answer directly. And I also agree the way it was put was confusing... Thus, another edit proposal.

Comment: 50 rep is required before commenting is enabled. The user here (@Ryan) is still only at 21.

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to rip out a drive without disconnecting it properly, the OS may be using it at the time you pull it even if you're not explicitly using it; the OS has to keep track of drives and paths and sizes, etc.

Also there may be some other power or current running to the drive perhaps the drive it's self it asking for power to run, say, an LED or what have you, or just a "micro brain" inside the drive itself and if you pull the plug it can create an arc across the pins that may not only damage your drive but your USB socket itself, rendering it useless for the future (meaning you'll need to get it fixed).

Comment: If you can "feel" that your hard drive is spun down anyway, you can safely unplug it. However you still get this annoying message then.Scenario: Portable drive on your home theatre Mac and you don't want to turn on your TV just to eject your drive.

Answer (score 0):

[Post on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly)

 Use at own risk, dataloss is **possible** if not safe ejecting!